# Loading FIPS OpenSSL DLL at a fixed base address on Windows

Tags: windows, dll, openssl, fips, aslr

A FIPS validated OpenSSL library must load libeay32.dll at a fixed address.
This is indicated, for example, at: [Fixed address is occupied in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30974018/fixed-address-is-occupied-in-net)

Using techniques described at: [IIS7 App Pool can't load library with Fixed Base Address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11232383/iis7-app-pool-cant-load-library-with-fixed-base-address), and
[How do you disable ASLR (address space layout randomization) on Windows 7 x64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560993/how-do-you-disable-aslr-address-space-layout-randomization-on-windows-7-x64), and
[How to run a PE image without linking kernel32.dll and ntdll.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7481572/how-to-run-a-pe-image-without-linking-kernel32-dll-and-ntdll-dll),
I've forced the loading of the FIPS DLL as early as I am able.

For a 64-bit process, from a ListDLLs output, I see a load order of:

```
E:\my\my64.exe
C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
E:\my\LIBEAY_FIPS32.dll
...
```

For a 32-bit process, there is some extra "wow" nonsense, namely:

```
E:\my\my32.exe
C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\wow64.dll
C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\wow64win.dll
C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\wow64cpu.dll
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll
C:\Windows\syswow64\kernel32.dll
C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
E:\my\LIBEAY_FIPS32.dll
...
```

Now, this is a huge improvement from what I started with, and the chances of getting a "0xc0000018 failed to load at FIXED address error" is now much lower than when LIBEAY_FIPS32.dll was around the 25th DLL loaded into the process.

However, given that these system DLLs are relocatable and presumably subject to ASLR, I expect load failures are still possible.

Though I don't want to switch off Windows ASLR, I would like to somehow tell ASLR to "please avoid the following FIXED address range because I really need to load a FIXED DLL at that address". Is there any way to do that?

Or some way to control the load address of one or more of: ntdll.dll, kernel32.dll, kernelbase.dll?

Failing that, is there any way to force the FIPS openssl dll to load into a process before one or more of: ntdll.dll, kernel32.dll, kernelbase.dll?